# adding pagelayouts from layouts folder

Tags: 2013, page-layout

I want to add pages for pagelayout. I have created 2 features i.e FeatureA and FeatureB. FeatureA and FeatureB will both use same pagelayouts.

I cannot create module for pagelayout because i will not be able to include it in both features. So i am planning to put pagelayouts in `_layouts` folder.

This [link](https://sacarter.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/spfeaturereceiver-set-the-page-layout-to-our-custom-home-page-layout-and-add-web-parts-to-appropriate-zones/)  i am trying to follow but it tries to fetch from `_catalogs` folder. How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page layouts need to reside in the master page gallery (under _catalogs/masterpage). You could create a feature with a module to deploy them there, and then make your features A and B be dependent on this one via [feature dependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231535.aspx)

Comment: But this is not correct either. Because my featureA will have other items than pagelayout. So if i keep dependency of featureA on featureB then it will add things from featureA. For example FeatureA has masterpage,pagelayouts and featureB has its own masterpage. So if i keep dependency on featureA while activating featureB then it will add master page from featureA?

Comment: What i meant is, create a new featureC with just the page layouts, and make both A and B depend on it

Answer (score 1):

The _layouts directory doesn't store page layouts, they need to be provisioned to the master page gallery.

The best option in your case would be to write Feature A with a module that would provision your page layout to the master page gallery and then you can write your Feature B with Feature dependency as Fran suggested in his answer. Alternatively in Feature B, you can write your Feature Activation code to check whether the Feature A is activated already and whether the page layout already exists.